# Unable to communicate between pods on kubernetes on rancher using google cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, devops, rancher

I have created orderer and cli pods. When i go to cli shell and create channel then it is not able to connect with ordrer.

*Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded*

The port for order ie. `7050` is open and when i go to orderer shell and do `telnet localhost 7050` it is connected but when specify the ip for pod then it does not work.

I am using Google Cloud for deloyment. I have also added firewall rules for ingress and egress for all IP and all Ports.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the snippets of your Deployments, Services? And also outputs of `kubectl -n <your_app_namespace> get pods,deploy,svc,ep -o wide`?

Comment: _do telnet localhost 7050 it is connected but when specify the ip for pod then it does not work_ sounds suspiciously like the service is only listening on localhost, and not `0.0.0.0` or the Pod's hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing this variable

```
ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS = 0.0.0.0
```

After adding this variable it worked